# Azure Media Streaming Delay

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, azure-media-services

So I have a list of thumbnails of videos.  I have a Video html object that gets loaded with the correct sources once I click on the thumbnail of the video I want to watch.  The sources are loading up quickly and fine and the video plays.  About 1 out of 3 times though, I click a video and the call to my media service streaming endpoint takes about 20 seconds or more to complete.  I'm not making this call directly, this is a result of changing the sources in the video object via knockout.  This whole time the thumbnail is loaded in the video object and the controls are loaded but the video can't play.  My question is, how can I intercept that event and show the video player after the streaming endpoint is set up so people aren't sitting there for 20 seconds thinking the thing doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong direction for the answer.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_audio_video.htm